# DocuSign API pass thru OneLogin

Tags: docusignapi, onelogin

We have a application written for a client that sits behind the client's OneLogin page. Our app is expecting DocuSign data via the API call to hit a REST endpoint.  My question is that since the DocuSign API interface seems limited to BasicAuth for the API call, is there a way setup in OneLogin some type of pass thru for the API or just have OneLogin accept the BasicAuth. Sorry, I don't have any experience using OneLogin or configuring it.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please more details how OneLogin is configured to call DS API? Are your users using OneLogin and then your App is called from OneLogin to trigger DS API?

Comment: I’ve done some testing today and I think I’m good but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign's REST API does not use Basic Auth. Our outbound web hook service, DocuSign Connect, can *optionally* use Basic Auth to authenticate with customers' listener servers.

The DocuSign APIs use OAuth.